# place center td tag in tr tag which is colspan applied

Tags: html-table

```
<tr>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>438</td>
   <td>$195</td>
   <td>Sa</td>
   <td>De</td>   
</tr>

                        
<tr class="prevrec">
   <td colspan="4">Delivered</td>
</tr>
```

Please help me to align td in second tr tag which is colspan applied.

margin 0 auto is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
td[colspan="4"] {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Updated**:

```
<td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">Delivered</td>
```

Comment: thank you for help but still not working... still in left side

Comment: Must try with css width, I had same issue , fixed it with width